# Elasticsearch: Look for a term at the end of text

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing the following documents in Elasticsearch 5.x:

```
{
    "id": 1
    "description": "The quick brown fox"
}

{
    "id": 2
    "description": "The fox runs fast"
}
```

If I search for the word `"fox"` in these documents, I will get both of them.
 How can I find documents that their `description` field ends with the word `"fox"`? In the above example, I am looking the one with `id=1`

If possible, I prefer to do this with a [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Well regex should work. Note if you have to look for endwith a lot of time, reindex using a analyzer will be the best (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-ends-with-word-in-phrases/60473)

```
"regexp":{
            "id": {
                "value": "*fox",
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will look for all terms ending with `fox`. For example, it will also match the string "I use firefox as my browser"

Comment: Your description field is indexed with default, so not as a keyword? So yes ES could change order of word (and will do it for sure). So your have to add an analyzer in your mappings (use the link i posted). "analyzer": {
        "analyzer_endswith":{
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "type": "standard",
            "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "reverse"
            ]
        }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your index mapping includes a [keyword field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) for the description. For example:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Add the documents:

```
POST my_index/_doc
{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "The quick brown fox"
}

POST my_index/_doc
{
    "id": 2,
    "description": "The fox runs fast"
}
```

And use a query string like this:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "description.keyword",
            "query" : "*fox"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so no way to do this with the `text` field?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic uses [Lucene's Regex](https://help.oncrawl.com/en/articles/1685982-lucene-regex-cheat-sheet) engine, which doesn't support [everything](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html). To solve your particular problem however, you can use wildcard search or regexp search like so:

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "description.keyword": {
        "value": "*able"
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp":{
      "description.keyword": {
        "value": "[a-zA-Z0-9]+fox",
        "flags": "ALL", 
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```